# How to update httpd.conf file in openshift

Tags: openshift, openshift-php-cartidges

Is there a way to apply Apache server config (in httpd.conf) to Openshift PHP application? I need to add a configuration so that Apache acts as reverse proxy for specific URL pattern and those requests need to be handled by a java application also hosted in Openshift. But I do not have access to httpd.conf file and only root user has access to it. The file I am referring to is (php/configuration/etc/conf/httpd.conf)

Answer (score 0):

The users do not have permissions to edit the `hhtpd.conf` file in PHP cartridges I know of.

However, you can develop your own cartridge, that will have it configured according to your needs. You can find more about creating cartridges [here](https://docs.openshift.org/origin-m4/oo_cartridge_developers_guide.html).